# Prevent user access to console but still allow svn+ssh:// access to SVN repos

Tags: ssh, svn, ssh-tunnel, hacking

I create an user `john` on my server and I add him into the SVN group so we can share our code and everything looks okay. Now I want to prevent this user from connecting to the console or shell via SSH. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_confing` file I add this lines:

```
Match User john
  ForceCommand svnserve -t
```

I would like to ask if is my configuration safe enough? SVN commands over SSH works fine. When he tries to connect, he gets:

```
blueprint:~ john$ ssh john@91.***.***.96 -p **5
john@91.***.***.96's password:
( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay ) ) )

^CConnection to 91.***.***.96 closed.
blueprint:~ john$
```

I have two questions:

- Is this it? Is there a way for a `john` to login on my server on a somehow hackable way?
- Does exist an option on server to return him a nice message `You do not have permission to login!` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a correct way how to do it. I have just two points how you may additionally improve security of your SVN server.

Firstly, you can allow SSH public key authentication only. If so, you can then lock user's password with

```
passwd -l USERNAME
```

Secondly, you can create a simple wrapper script (spawned shell is replaced with `svnserve` command) and use it with `ForceCommand` option which includes warning message

```
cat > /usr/local/bin/svn_cmd_wrapper.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh -f

echo "You do not have permission to login!"
echo
exec svnserve -t
EOF
```

Then, make it executable

```
chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/svn_cmd_wrapper.sh
```

and use it in `sshd_config` file:

```
ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/svn_cmd_wrapper.sh
```

Comment: I will think about public key authentication.
You forget quotation marks at the end of the first echo and I had to change permission and group (`chown root:svn svn_cmd_wrapper.sh` and `chmod 754 svn_cmd_wrapper.sh`) Anyway I like your idea. Is there a way to recognize `svnserve -t` command and allow it and notify the user about permissions for any other command?

Comment: We just put the following at the start of the authorized_key line: command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r /var/svn",no-agent-forwarding,no-pty,no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding